# Uso extraño del verbo "suponer"

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Quisiera que me explicáseis el sentido del verbo **suponer** en la siguiente frase:

> *Poema del Cante Jondo* y el *Romancero gitano* representan la transfiguración poética del tema de Andalucía, en tono puramente lírico en la primera obra y con acentos dramáticos en la segunda. Las dos ***suponen*** la cima esencial de la poesía de Garcia Lorca [...]
>   Extracto de la descripción editorial del libro *Poema del Cante Jondo / Romancero Gitano* de Federico García Lorca - Ediciones Cátedra (2006)

Tengo entendido que en tal contexto significa algo así como 'representar', pero a mi parecer le añade una matiz que no logro entender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No estoy totalmente de acuerdo con la respuesta de Obie 2.0, yo me decanto más bien por la quinta acepción de [**suponer**](https://dle.rae.es/suponer) detallada en el DRAE

> 5. tr. Tener determinado **valor** o importancia. 
>    *¿Cuánto supone un billete más? Ella supone mucho para mí. Felipe supone mucho en la
>      empresa.*

Fíjate en el segundo ejemplo: Ella supone mucho para mí.
¿Qué suponen esos dos títulos dentro de la obra del poeta? ¿Cuál es su **valor**? Son la cima esencial.

No acabo de ver la implicación. ¿Cómo podemos inferir que esas dos obras son la cima esencial sin compararlas (**valorarlas**) respecto a las demás?

¿Cuál de estas dos frases tiene más sentido?

> Las dos implican la cima esencial de su obra.
>  Las dos se valoran como
>   la cima esencial de su obra.

Yo veo una **identificación** entre dos elementos, ese libro y la esencia, más que una implicación.
 A = B y no A -> B.

Answer (score 3):

En este caso, supongo que [la cuarta acepción](https://dle.rae.es/suponer) de la RAE es la adecuada.

> 4. Implicar o llevar consigo algo.

Dicho de otra manera, los dos poemas implican "la cima esencial" de la poesía de Lorca. Su publicación llevó consigo esa cima.

Otros ejemplos similares serían "suponer el fin de algo", o  "suponer un cambio."

De todos modos, no sé si las definiciones de la RAE engloban todos los posibles matices, porque casi podríamos sustituir "suponen" por "son" o por "representan" sin cambiar demasiado el significado. Cuando una cosa implica otra, a veces las dos casi son idénticas.